# How to reduce button click area (only to the button)

Tags: java, button, javafx

I've got a simple password generator in JavaFX. Whenever I click the button, a password is generated but also when I click somewhere else in the application area, the button also reacts. How can I reduce the click area?

Main

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/main.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Password Generator");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(610.0);
        primaryStage.setMaxHeight(450.0);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(600.0);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Main.fxml

```xml
<Pane fx:id="mainPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="416.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
   <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onMouseClicked="#generatePassword" prefHeight="417.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ed801a;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
      <children>
         <Button fx:id="generatePassword" layoutX="206.0" layoutY="216.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#generatePassword" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="188.0" text="Generate">
            <font>
               <Font name="System Italic" size="20.0" />
            </font>
         </Button>
      </children>
   </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: Note: It's better to use `onAction` instead `onMouseClicked` for `Button`.This way you also get the events, if you use the enter key with the button focused and do not need to check, if the click was done with the primary mouse button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onMouseClicked="#generatePassword" prefHeight="417.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ed801a;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

Remove the `onMouseClicked="#generatePassword"` from the `AnchorPane` declaration.